# Не получается запустить Php Unit

Tags: php, composer, phpunit

OpenServer. Установлен Composer, PhpUnit.

Ввожу `vendor/bin/phpunit`

Выводит:

> "vendor" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
>   программой или пакетным файлом.

Почему возникает данная проблема ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запуск идет с обратным слешем:

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```